# Create a notification on Android with Python 3 - without Google Play Services

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, notifications

I have a Python 3 program which periodically connects to a foreign server and makes an API request using the `requests` module. Currently I used `notify2` to display notifications on desktop.

```
import notify2


def show_notification(msg):
    notify2.init(APPNAME_HUMAN)
    notification = notify2.Notification(
        APPNAME_HUMAN,
        msg,
        "icon-name")
    notification.show()
```

Now I'd like to do the same on Android. How can I do it? There are `pushnotify` and `python-gcm` but they refer to another thing: I want a local notification, not a push notification.